# UIButton not responding to fast tapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am making a calculator. The UIButtons I am using for the numbers are being sluggish in that they do not accept a second tap for at least half a second while the button has finished it's default glow animation after a tap.
For example, if I quickly tap a number is only adds every other tap to the calculator display.
Is there a way that I can get the button to respond quicker or do you think the glow animation on touch is responsible?
If I tap different buttons quickly they are responsive, so that rules out inefficient coding.
Thanks

Comment: There is an error in your code, provide it in order to get help.

Comment: Code would be useful. Another idea is to check the event you're using: if you're listening for "touch up inside" you could switch to "touch down" and see if that helps.

Comment: call action on button on TouchDown instead of TouchUpInside (Which is default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this strange issue by adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to the button and setting the target to run the code that the IBAction would have otherwise.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOne = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buttonOneTapped)];
    [one addGestureRecognizer:tapOne];
```

Then just made sure to disconnect the IBAction link from storyboard. Now it receives the quick taps that I need.
I think this had something to do with the fact that I had applied a radius to the buttons. Still unsure.